# Upper/lower regexp char classes and current-case-table

Tags: regular-expressions, unicode

I seem to have a problem with `[:upper:]` `[:lower:]` and Unicode characters.

This test fails:

```
(ert-deftest haskell-upper ()
  (set-buffer (get-buffer-create "*haskell-mode-buffer*"))
  (insert "Ż")
  (goto-char (point-min))
  (should (looking-at "[[:upper:]]")))
```

This one (surprisingly) succeeds:

```
(ert-deftest haskell-upper ()
  (set-buffer (get-buffer-create "*haskell-mode-buffer*"))
  (insert "Ż")
  (goto-char (point-min))
  (should (looking-at "[[:lower:]]")))
```

Note that

```
(message "%c" (char-table-range (current-case-table) ?Ż))
```

correctly returns

```
ż
```

So case table seems to be setup correctly but regexp machinery does not pick this up. Note that this is a problem only when running in batch mode, in interactive mode it works as expected.

Is there some initialization code that needs to be called before using `looking-at`, char classes and Unicode?

My version of Emacs:
Aquamacs 3.2 GNU Emacs 24.4.51.2 (x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0, NS apple-appkit-1343.14) of 2014-11-07 (Aquamacs-3.2) on watson.local

It also fails in the same way on Emacs 23.3.1 and Emacs 25.0.50.1.

Comment: Where are these characters inserted ?

Comment: Added the answer in the code: in temporary buffers created just for a test.

Comment: Of course this'll only work if this buffer is indeed empty.

Comment: It seems that `case-fold-search` has an effect on `[:upper:]`.

Comment: `case-fold-search is the problem`. @politza if you make an answer I can accept it.

Comment: This describes the bug I've hit: http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=18150